# AngularFire - How to push collection items into an array

Tags: arrays, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have an AngularFire collection query from firestore. I would like to push each of the returned items into my array. Below is what I have tried so far.

The result is that only the last item is entered into the array. If I remove `this.myArr = [];` from inside the query, all the results appear in the array on load. However, as you can imagine, when a new item is added, everything is readded to the array, opposed to the latest item. I assume that for each item, the array is being cleared, and then added to, hence the last item only being added.

How do I ensure that each item is added to the array, and not just the last?

```
 this.myArr = [];

   ...

  issueData() {
    this.albumCollection = this.afs.collection<any>(`album/albumID}/issues`, ref => {
      return ref.orderBy('order');
    });

    this.issues = this.albumCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {

        const data = a.payload.doc.data();
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;

        this.myArr = [];
        this.myArr.push({ id, ...data });

        return { id, ...data };

      }))
    );
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div *ngFor="let issue of myArr"> a </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use a specific variable when your observable return already your array?

```
issueData() {
    this.albumCollection = this.afs.collection<any>(`album/albumID}/issues`, ref => {
      return ref.orderBy('order');
    });

    this.issues = this.albumCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(actions => actions.map(a => {

            const data = a.payload.doc.data();
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;


            return { id, ...data };

        }))
    );
}
```

Then, in your template, your subscribe to your observable to access the data:

```
<div *ngFor="let issue of issues | async">{{issue | json}}</div>
```

If your really need a variable to cache your result, you can use a tap operator (no need to push yourself data into the array):

```
this.myArr = [];

issueData() {
    this.albumCollection = this.afs.collection<any>(`album/albumID}/issues`, ref => {
      return ref.orderBy('order');
    });

    this.issues = this.albumCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
       map(actions => actions.map(a => {

         const data = a.payload.doc.data();
         const id = a.payload.doc.id;


         return { id, ...data };

       })),
       tap(data => this.myArr = data)
   );
}
```

But don't forget that you will have to subscribe to the observable to feed  `this.myArr`, otherwise, it will stay empty.